# problema con libreria FPDF.php

Tags: php, fpdf

al ejecutar mi codigo la terminal me dice que hay un error en $this->fontpath = FPDF_FONTPATH en la linea 267 de la libreria FPDF (la libreria esta en el mismo directorio). Para ser mas especifico dice:

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Could not include font definition file: C:\xampp\htdocs\ArgPro_PHPDeveloper\Modulo2\Clase4\Practico7\Punto2/font/helveticab.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\ArgPro_PHPDeveloper\Modulo2\Clase4\Practico7\Punto2\fpdf.php:267

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Encabezado
    function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Argentina Programa', 0, 1, 'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
    }

    // Pie de página
    function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'apellido nombre alumno', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
}

// Crear el documento PDF
$pdf = newPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

// Cuerpo del PDF
$text = 'TEXTO.';

$pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, $text);

// Salida del PDF
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente el error te dice que no encuentra la fuente para renderizar el texto. Asegurate de que el directorio *font* se encuente al mismo nivel que el archivo fpdf.php y que la fuente exista (de forma predeterminada fpdf viene con las fuentes helvetica, symbol y times)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solución 1

Primero revisa que la carpeta `font` se encuentra al mismo nivel del script `fpdf.php` y después agrega a tu archivo la siguiente linea antes de agregar `require('fpdf.php');`

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');
```

#### Solución 2

Lo que ocasiona este error es que en el archivo `fpdf.php` se valida si esta definida la constante `FPDF_FONTPATH` y por algún motivo la validación se cumple aunque no esté definida, al cumplir esta condición se asigna esta constante a la propiedad `$this->fontpath`.

Código original versión 1.86, linea 105

```
// Font path
if(defined('FPDF_FONTPATH'))
    $this->fontpath = FPDF_FONTPATH;
else
    $this->fontpath = dirname(__FILE__).'/font/';
```

Si no usas fuentes adicionales a las que traer FPDF de forma predefinida cambialo por lo sigueinte:

```
// Font path
$this->fontpath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/font/';
```

Ten en cuenta que la carpeta `font` se debe ubicar al mismo nivel del script fpdf.php

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo html2pdf en javascript, pues solo creas el contenido html y con ese mismo creas el pdf sin necesidad de pasar linea por linea avísame  te digo como puedes hacer la integración

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Debes participar más para obtener reputación y poder comentar. Puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada.